# codecs.open create txt file in specific path Python

Tags: python, file, text

i have this code but it saves the files in the same path of .py file, how can i do to create txt files in specific folder?

```
f = codecs.open("gabili" + '.txt', mode="w", encoding="utf-16")
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
f.write(u"[HELLO] *ASDASD* /(&) \n")
```

Comment: Give `open` a path such as `C:/Documents/gabili.txt`

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?#codecs.open) fonction takes a *filename* parameter.
This *filename* can be a file name or a full path.
So, you can use `"/full/path/to/gabili.txt"`.

To build a full path, you can use `os.path` package, like this.

```
import os

fullpath = os.path.join("/full", "path", "to", "gabili.txt)
```

Then use it in `codecs.open` parameters:

```
with codecs.open(fullpath, mode="w", encoding="utf-16") as f:
    f.write(u"[HELLO] *ASDASD* /(&) \n")
```

*NOTE1: the recommanded way to open a file is by using a `with` statement*

*NOTE2: to be portable Py2/Py3, you should use `io.open` instead of `codecs.open`*

```
import io

with io.open(fullpath, mode="w", encoding="utf-16") as f:
    f.write(u"[HELLO] *ASDASD* /(&) \n")
```